# Apple iOS Multicast using Godot 4.2.1, C#, Xcode

Tags: c#, ios, godot, multicast

I am using Godot 4.2.1 and C# (.NET 8.0.1) to create an app. In Godot the app is exported to an Xcode project so it can then be built to run on IOS devices. Access WiFi is checked in the Godot presets I have the multicast entitlement from Apple. Communication over UDP using Unicast to send and receive packets works correctly on iOS, macOS and Android devices.

To set the multicast entitlement, the project name is selected in Xcode, to open a big dialog box with multiple tabs. Click on the tab Signing and Capabilities. To add the multicast to the project "+ Capability" is clicked, search for "multi" which brings up multicast networking. Click on multicast networking to add it to the project.
[image: Add Multicast Entitlement]

Then in the same dialog box, click the tab build settings and under "Signing" code signing identity is changed to iOS developer for all Debug and release items.

[image: Build Setting update]

The project is then built and run on the iOS device. The symptom is that no multicast packets are received.

The multicast receiving code below works on macOS and Android devices so there must be something going on with the iOS devices that I'm missing.

The UDP server is configured in C# code as a _listener:

```
 private const string MULTICAST_ADDRESS = "239.255.1.1";
 private const int BCON_PORT = 49707;

_listener = new UdpClient();
_listener.ExclusiveAddressUse = false;
_listener.JoinMulticastGroup(IPAddress.Parse(MULTICAST_ADDRESS));
_listener.Client.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, BCON_PORT));
```